# Influx CLI batch import bad timestamp

Tags: influxdb

I am new to Influxdb and working in a windows environment, trying to import a file for batch insert.. appreciate any help Thanks.

Below is the sample format of the file I am terminating every with line feed (\n)

```
# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: StatsArchive
# CONTEXT-RETENTION-POLICY: oneyear
DbSpaceUsage,Servername=test,DatabaseName=testdb,FileType=log,FileSizeMb=222999 AvgUsedSpaceMB=191883i MinUsedSpaceMB=191089i MaxUsedSpaceMB=192198i 1442188800
DbSpaceUsage,Servername=test,DatabaseName=testdb,FileType=Data,FileSizeMb=55996 AvgUsedSpaceMB=160i MinUsedSpaceMB=47i MaxUsedSpaceMB=357i 1442361600
```

Output:

```
influx.exe -import -path=C:\stats.csv -precision=s

2016/07/19 22:39:08 error writing batch:  {"error":"unable to parse 'DbSpaceUsage,Servername=test,DatabaseName=testdb,FileType=log,FileSizeMb=222999 AvgUsedSpaceMB=191883i MinUsedSpaceMB=191089i MaxUsedSpaceMB=192198i 1442188800': bad timestamp\nunable to parse 'DbSpaceUsage,Servername=test,DatabaseName=testdb,FileType=Data,FileSizeMb=55996 AvgUsedSpaceMB=160i MinUsedSpaceMB=47i MaxUsedSpaceMB=357i 1442361600': bad timestamp\nunable to parse
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data that you've listed isn't in line-protocol. The general structure of line-protocol is as follows:

```
<measurement>[,<tag>[,<tag>] ...] <field>[,<field> ...] <timestamp>
```

I've adjusted the example you've given to be in line protocol below:

```
# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: StatsArchive
# CONTEXT-RETENTION-POLICY: oneyear
DbSpaceUsage,Servername=test,DatabaseName=testdb,FileType=log FileSizeMb=222999,AvgUsedSpaceMB=191883i,MinUsedSpaceMB=191089i,MaxUsedSpaceMB=192198i 1442188800
DbSpaceUsage,Servername=test,DatabaseName=testdb,FileType=Data FileSizeMb=55996,AvgUsedSpaceMB=160i,MinUsedSpaceMB=47i,MaxUsedSpaceMB=357i 1442361600
```